# How to implement content security policy with NWebsec

Tags: c#, nwebsec

I am implementing content security policy in Asp.Net application.(.Net Framework 3.5). I have installed NWebSec (4.0) through nuget packages and added blow configuration in web.config.

```
<nwebsec>
 <httpHeaderSecurityModule>
    <securityHttpHeaders>
    <content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
          <default-src self="true"/>
          <script-src self="true" unsafeInline= "true">
             <add source="*.abc.com" />
              </script-src>
    </content-Security-Policy>
   </securityHttpHeaders>
  </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
 </nwebsec>
```

The above configuration generates below header

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src ‘self’; script-src ‘self’ 'unsafe-inline' *.abc.com`

But I believe, the above header is missing 'nonce' tag it must be something like

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src ‘self’; script-src ‘self’ 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-Koegbg1128522' *.abc.com`

Why am I not getting this 'nonce' tag in header?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are under the impression that a nonce should be added by the provided configuration. AFAIK, If you want to use nonce with NWebSec, you have to also use the htmlHelper CspStyleNonce function like such

```
<script @Html.CspScriptNonce()>document.write("Hello world")</script>
```

Or if you prefer to use bundling

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\" " + @Html.CspScriptNonce() + "></script>","<Path to script bundle>")
```

More information could be found on the [official NwebSec documentation](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/aspnet4/nwebsec/Configuring-csp.html#script-and-style-nonces-through-htmlhelpers)